# Select all results from two independent tables

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables:

```
Comments
--------
id
comment_content
time_stamp

Activities
-----------
id
activity_content
time_stamp
```

And I would like to combine the results from both, ordered by their timestamp fields.

Comment: How would you combine the values? What is common beside a time_stamp?

Comment: nothing is common, that is why they are independent.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two tables with `UNION` and `ORDER BY timestamp`. You can also add an addition (`type`) column so the source of a row can be identified:

```
SELECT 
    'comment' AS type, id, comment_content AS content, time_stamp
FROM
    comments

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'activity', id, activity_content, time_stamp
FROM
    activities

ORDER BY 
    timestamp ;
```